# forward declare static function c++

Tags: c++

I want to forward declare a static member function of a class in another file. What I WANT to do looks like this:

BigMassiveHeader.h:

```
class foo
{
    static void init_foos();
}
```

Main.cpp:

```
class foo;
void foo::init_foos();
int main(char** argv, int argc)
{
    foo::init_foos()
}
```

This fails out with "error C2027: use of undefined type 'foo'"

Is there a way to accomplish what I want to do with out making init_foos a free function, or including BigMassiveHeader.h? (BigMassiveHeader.h is noticeably effecting compile time, and is included everywhere.)

Comment: Whether to include code in the .cpp or in BigHeader.h shouldn't have an effect. After all, you ARE using #include guards or #pragma once so BigHeader.h only gets compiled once, right?

Comment: @Kyte Include guards limit BigHeader.h to once per translation unit where it is included.  If it is being included in many source files, it will need to be compiled many times.

Comment: So would it be possible to split out the definition of `class foo` into another header file?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You cannot forward declare members of a class, regardless of whether they are static or not.

In Main.cpp the class `foo` is an incomplete type. It is unknown for the compiler what function and data members it has. So the compiler issues an error for this declaration `void foo::init_foos();`.

Comment: It's not even a forward declaration of `foo::init_foos();`, but rather a declaration of a global function called `init_foos()`.

Comment: Strictly speaking, the C++ parlance has no such term as "forward declare". In common speak "forward declare" normally means "declare without defining". Taking this into account, it is possible to "forward declare" a member function. Every time you *define* a class, you are "forward declaring" its [non-inline] member functions. The right answer would be: you can't *declare* a class member without *defining* the class. James McNellis's deleted answer was actually the formally correct one.

Comment: @AndreyT:  The Standard section 27.2 is titled "Forward declarations", and there's an index entry in TC++PL special edition.

Comment: @David Thornley: OK, fair enough. I'd still insist that the term is used informally. More precisely, it describes the purpose of these declarations, not the formal properties of declarations themselves.

Comment: @AndreyT i agree with you that "forward declaration" is used informally only (same for "prototype"). But i think James' answer was't formally correct, because static member functions can be declared outside the class very well (if that declaration is a definition or if that declaration happens inside another class in a friend function declaration). Only the first declaration of it has to occur inside the class.

Comment: Why isn't this allowed? From the point of view of someone running into this limitation, it looks rather odd to have all the definitions inside the class, except for that one function that, because we'd like to "forward declare" it, must have its definition outside the class. Why can't the compiler detect that a "duplicate declaration" that happens to have a definition with it as the definition of the previous "forward declaration"? Seems like most of the detection machinery exists already, because otherwise the current error message couldn't be delivered corectly.

Comment: that seems like an incredibly dumb decision by c++ standard committee

Answer (score 5):

You can't forward declare members of your class but you could make a namespace and a function inside of that namespace and forward declare that.

```
namespace nsfoo
{
     void init_foos();
}
```

Your class if needed could friend this function.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a `BigMassiveHeader`, you should consider splitting it up into several `SmallCompactHeaders`. If you want to express that many classes and functions belong together semantically, you can put them in the same namespace. You can always provide a convenience-header that includes all your small headers.

Comment: We are well aware of this. The refactoring of BigMassiveHeader is a bit of technical debt that we inherited from predecessors, and are paying in installments. This, in fact is pare of that effort.

Answer (score 0):

You can't partially declare classes in C++, so either you'll have to put the class's declaration in its own, smaller header, or...

Include `BigMassiveHeader.h` in your file and use precompiled headers.
The Visual C++ way: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yzw0wyd%28v=VS.71%29.aspx, or the GCC way: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Precompiled-Headers.html.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not the point of the question, but if BigMassiveHeader.h is not likely to change much over time, you should take a look at [precompiled headers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precompiled_header)

Answer (score 0):

As a first refactoring, I'd use a free function which calls the static function. It's not like your main method is getting called lots of times, so you won't notice an extra call, and that makes the least change to the existing code.

Of course, you don't actually say what you are trying to do, only what you want to do. If what you are trying to do is get `init_foos` called once on application start, use static object initialisation for that, rather than calling it in main. If what you are trying to do is get `init_foos` called after all static objects are created, then it's more complicated.

By static object initialisation, I mean something like having this in a .cpp file which has access to the definition of `init_foos`. Make it a friend and `init_foos` private to prevent multiple calls:

```
struct call_init_foos {
  call_init_foos () { foo::init_foos(); }
} call_init_foos_on_startup;
```

Answer (score -1):

No, you need to include the header for that. Sorry.

Use a free function if you must, or split the class.

Answer (score -1):

to forward declaration of a single method of a class, you must declare the method as part of the class (as it really is).

for example, in your case, add to main.cpp:

```
class foo
{
public:
    static void init_foos();
}
```

its not the prettiest, but it will save you having to include the whole header..

Comment: that will end with redefinition if you include that file in same place as original class....