# Using static const member before declaration

Tags: c++, static-members, forward-declaration

My problem is the following:

```
template<typename T> 
struct A {
    T* array[B<T>::N];
};

template<typename T>
struct B {
    static const int N = 10;
    A<T> a;
}
```

This does not compile, because I would need some kind of forward declaration. I see two options

- change the order of the class declarations + forward declaration of `A` so I can use a pointer of `A` in `B`. I dont like it because I really would like to have `A` and not `A*` as member in `B`
- make `N` a template parameter of `A`. For now I guess I will go with this, but I also dont like it too much, thus I would like to know...

Is there a way to make this code compile (if possible without changing any of the types or introducing more template parameters)?

There are many similar questions, but to most of them the answer is something along the line: "No you cant forward (static) class members"
Here are some of them:

[forward declare static function c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655612/forward-declare-static-function-c)

[Is it possible to forward declare a static array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936446/is-it-possible-to-forward-declare-a-static-array)

[c++ forward declaration of a static class member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15806331/c-forward-declaration-of-a-static-class-member)

Comment: Shouldn't that `T* array[B::N];` be `T* array[B<T>::N];`?

Comment: @ChristianHackl yes, I fixed it. Actually I also had the same mistake in the original code, but I didnt realize it yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the classes a bit to get around the problem.

**Solution 1: Make `N` a member of `A`**

```
template<typename T> 
struct A {
    static const int N = 10;
    T* array[N];
};
```

and define `B<T>::N` in terms of `A<T>::N`.

```
template<typename T>
struct B {
    static const int N = A<T>::N;
    A<T> a;
};
```

**Solution 2: Make `N` another template parameter of `A`**

```
template<typename T, int N> 
struct A {
    T* array[N];
};

template<typename T>
struct B {
    static const int N = 10;
    A<T, N> a;
};
```